# Remove native base FABs ripple effect on android

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I'm having problem with native base FAB button it shows a square ripple effect when i press it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an issue in native base , try this workaround solution :
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2313

> ```
> <Fab
>    containerStyle={{ borderRadius: 28, overflow: "hidden" }}>
>    // inner elements
> </Fab>
> ```

Comment: You could have just posted that code here, as it would be easier for future readers to get the information they need. I would consider posting the workaround code and if you can try to explain how it helps work-around OP's situation.